# SQL query: same rows

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, sqldf

I'm having trouble finding the right sql query. I want to select all the rows with a unique x value and if there are rows with the same x value, then I want to select the row with the greatest y value. As an example I've put a part of my database below.

```
    ID  x   y
    1   2   3
    2   1   5
    3   4   6
    4   4   7
    5   2   6
```

The selected rows should then be those with ID 2, 4 and 5.

This is what I've got so far

```
SELECT *
FROM base
WHERE x IN
     (
          SELECT x 
          FROM base
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     )
```

But this only results in the rows that occur more than once. I've added the tags R, postgresql and sqldf because I'm working in R with those packages.

Comment: Please edit the question to include sample results for the data you provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a typical way to formulate the query in ANSI SQL:

```
select b.*
from base b
where not exists (select 1
                  from base b2
                  where b2.x = b.x and
                        b2.y > b.y
                 );
```

In Postgres, you would use `distinct on` for performance:

```
select distinct on (x) b.*
from base b
order by x, y desc;
```

Comment: you will also have to union with a select to get the other half of the set, that selects the Y value when there's no X value

Comment: @JamesB . . . I'm not sure what your comment refers to.  All the rows have both an `x` and `y` value in the question and there is no mention of not having an `x` value.

Comment: fair enough, I misunderstood from the way the question was first worded (my comment doesn't make sense now!)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this query:

```
select x, max(y) from base group by x;
```

And, if you'd also like the `id` column in the result:

```
select base.*
from base join (select x, max(y) from base group by x) as maxima
    on (base.x = maxima.x and base.y = maxima.max);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

`CREATE TABLE tmp(id int, x int ,y int);
INSERT INTO .....`

test=# SELECT x, max(y) AS y FROM tmp GROUP BY x;
 x | y 
---+---
 4 | 7
 1 | 5
 2 | 6